# Create record in MySQL table using Radio Buttons in Ruby on Rails App

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have created a fantasy golf App and I want the user to create an entry in the scores table by selecting golfers by selecting their radio buttons (Pick one golfer from each group basically). Here is a section of the form.

**Golfpicks.html**

```
            <% provide(:title, 'Golfers Picks') %>
             <%= form_for Score.new do |f| %>
                <h2>Pool 1</h2>
                <ul class="users">
                <%= field_set_tag do %>
                  <%= render Golfer.where(:golferid => 1) %>
                  <%= f.radio_button :golferidgroup1, false, :checked => true %>
                  <%= render Golfer.where(:golferid => 2) %>
                  <%= f.radio_button :golferidgroup1, false, :checked => true %>
                  <%= render Golfer.where(:golferid => 3) %>
                  <%= f.radio_button :golfergroupid1, false, :checked => true %>
                  <%= render Golfer.where(:golferid => 4) %>
                  <%= f.radio_button :golfergroupid1, false, :checked => true %>
                  <%= render Golfer.where(:golferid => 5) %>
                  <%= f.radio_button :golfergroupid1, false, :checked => true %>
                  <%= render Golfer.where(:golferid => 6) %>
                  <%= f.radio_button :golfergroupid1, false, :checked => true %>
                  <%= render Golfer.where(:golferid => 7) %>
                  <%= f.radio_button :golfergroupid1, false, :checked => true %>
                  <%= render Golfer.where(:golferid => 8) %>
                  <%= f.radio_button :golfergroupid1, false, :checked => true %>
                  <%= render Golfer.where(:golferid => 9) %>
                  <%= f.radio_button :golfergroupid1, false, :checked => true %>
                  <%= render Golfer.where(:golferid => 10) %>
                  <%= f.radio_button :golfergroupid1, false, :checked => true %>
                  <% end %>
                </ul>
                <h2>Pool 2</h2>
                <ul class="users">
                <%= field_set_tag do  %>
                  <%= render Golfer.where(:golferid => 11) %>
                  <%= f.radio_button :golferidgroup2, false, :checked => true %>
                  <%= render Golfer.where(:golferid => 12) %>
                  <%= f.radio_button :golfergroupid2, false, :checked => true %>
                  <%= render Golfer.where(:golferid => 13) %>
                  <%= f.radio_button :golfergroupid2, false, :checked => true %>
                  <%= render Golfer.where(:golferid => 14) %>
                  <%= f.radio_button :golfergroupid2, false, :checked => true %>
                  <%= render Golfer.where(:golferid => 15) %>
                  <%= f.radio_button :golfergroupid2, false, :checked => true %>
                  <%= render Golfer.where(:golferid => 16) %>
                  <%= f.radio_button :golfergroupid2, false, :checked => true %>
                  <%= render Golfer.where(:golferid => 17) %>
                  <%= f.radio_button :golfergroupid2, false, :checked => true %>
                  <%= render Golfer.where(:golferid => 18) %>
                  <%= f.radio_button :golfergroupid2, false, :checked => true %>
                  <%= render Golfer.where(:golferid => 19) %>
                  <%= f.radio_button :golfergroupid2, false, :checked => true %>
                  <%= render Golfer.where(:golferid => 20) %>
                  <%= f.radio_button :golfergroupid2, false, :checked => true %>
                <% end %>
                </ul>
                <% end %>
                </ul> 
                <%= f.submit "Enter my Team", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
            <% end %>
```

Here is my scores Helper

```
        class ScoresController < ApplicationController

              def index
                @scores = Score.paginate(page: params[:page])
              end

                 def create
                @score = Score.new(params[:score])    

                if @score.save
                  # Handle a successful save.
                else
                  render 'new'
                end
              end 

              private

                def user_params
                  params.require(:score).permit(:golferid1, :golferid2, :golferid3,
                                               :golferid4, :golferid5, :golferid6)
                end

              end
```

I need to record the golderid which will be taken from the golfers table add to the records in the score table. This is the tricky part for me. I also need to store the Users id which could be taken from their login and record that in the scores record as well.

Golfers table

```
            golfers (
            golferid INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            secondtname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
            country VARCHAR(50),
            worldranking int(3),
            tournamentposition int(2),
            group1 boolean,
            group2 boolean,
            group3 boolean,
            group4 boolean,
            group5 boolean,
            group6 boolean,
            day1score int(2),
            day2score int(2),
            day3score int(2),
            day4score int(2),
            totalscore int(3),
            golfscoretotal int(3)
            );
```

Scores table

```
            scoreid int(6) UN AI PK 
            userid int(11) 
            golfergroupid1 int(6) 
            golfscoretotal1 int(3) 
            golfergroupid2 int(6) 
            golfscoretotal2 int(3) 
            golfergroupid3 int(6) 
            golfscoretotal3 int(3) 
            golfergroupid4 int(6) 
            golfscoretotal4 int(3) 
            golfergroupid5 int(6) 
            golfscoretotal5 int(3) 
            golfergroupid6 int(6) 
            golfscoretotal6 int(3) 
            totalscore int(4)
```

Golfers Model in RoR

```
            class Golfer < ActiveRecord::Base
            belongs_to :score 

            end
```

Scores Model in RoR

```
            class Score < ActiveRecord::Base
            belongs_to :user

            end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Im stuck on this issue now for a few days.

Rgrds
Dave

Comment: Your code is really confusing to me. You got 20 queries in your view and your tables contain columns such as golferid3, golferid4 or group1, group2, etc. Maybe I'm just misunderstandig it, but I think your base design is off. Can you explain in plain English what it is you exactly want to achieve in your application?

Comment: apologies Peter: I have sixty golfers split up into six groups of ten. I want to create a record in the score table after the user selects one golfer from each group using a radio button. I then want to record the users id in the same record

Comment: Ive revised the code now so hopefully it makes more sense

Comment: Can a golfer belong to multiple groups?

Comment: No Peter. One golfer can only be chosen for any given score record

Comment: Join the chart conversation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102092/discussion-between-peter-de-ridder-and-david-mac).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<% {1 => 1, 2 => 11}.each_pair do |pull_no, start_no| %>
  <h2> <%= "Pool #{pull_no}"  %></h2>
  <ul class="users">
    <%= field_set_tag do %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :("golferidgroup#{pull_no}"), nil %>
      <% 10.times do |i| %>
        <%= render Golfer.where(:golferid => start_no + i) %>
        <%= f.radio_button :("golferidgroup#{pull_no}"), start_no + i, :checked => false %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```